# Laravel Polymorphic Relationships

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best method to handle an instance where there is no record for the polymorphic object.

```
   user_type A table ( user_id , username )

   user_type B table (user_id , username )

   event table (event_id, user_id, user_type )
```

Sample Data

A_table
user_id , username
1 , sam
2 , john

B_table
user_id, username
1, Don
2, Mike

Event_table
event_id, user_id, user_type
1,1,A // Record 1
2,2,B // Record 2
1,5,A // Record 3

Consider the following pseudo code :
       `Event instance ->user->username`

1) Running the above for Record 1 Should result in "Sam"
2) Running the above for Record 2 Should result in "Mike"

Imagine a 3rd case :

Where as "Event instance ->user" results in NULL.

How do we best tackle a situation like this apart from having to always check if the Object is null or not before every instance we use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method to go around this was to do a simple :

```
if ( ! $this->polymorfphic_object_method)
{
  // skip now
}
```